# Responsive CSS using foundation GRID

Tags: css

I have received one design from my designer and he wants to write CSS for him. I tried as below:

```
.o__header{
    width: 1080px;
    position:relative;
    left:40px;top:135px;
}

.o--text{font-size:14px;color:#fff;position:absolute;top:-210px}
.o--head {font-size:40px;color:#fff;position:absolute;top:-310px}
.o--image {position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0;}

<div class="o__header">
        <div small="6" medium="6" large="6">
            <h1 class="o--head">Page Header Goes Here</h1><br/>
            <p class="o--text">Small hep description here</p>
        </div>

        <div small="6" medium="6" large="6">
            <img src ="img/img.PNG" style="max-
            width: 100%;height:auto;" styleClass="o--image">
        </div>
</div>
```

where small,large and medium are custom created mixins.
But this approach is not working great. I want it resposnive too. How to go about that? 
below is the layout

[image]

Comment: There isn't a 'make responsive for me' css property sadly. here are some learning resources: [using media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en), [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and [building a  responsive site](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756)

Comment: i can make it responsive and that is all fine. But how to align image and text as shown via CSS.

Comment: how to align it when, how?, what resolution? what device? what is your css not doing now? what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @atmd. i want it on any resolution. I am stuck on part that image is not getting displayed here and there but not on position where it is needed

Comment: please create a jsfiddle to demo what you have and what you are wanting so it's clearer what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @atymd.. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ynsk03h2/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72028/discussion-between-gags-and-atmd).